# Error 2002 when running mysql (with sudo as well)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-16.04, 32-bit, mysql-error-2002

I'm trying to use MySQL to make a login system and I keep getting this error.

```
winfinity@pcname:~$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
(2)
```

I've tried multiple answers. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
winfinity@pcname:~$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
(2)
```

The above error implies the file `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is missing, it can happen if `mysql-server` is not installed.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But if `mysql-server` is installed properly and is running, then check for config files.

```
/etc/my.cnf (socket file config may be /tmp/mysql.sock)
 OR
/etc/mysql/my.cnf (socket file config may be /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock)
```

In your case, it seems like the second config is set, so remove or rename `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, let mysql use `/etc/my.cnf`, this may fix your problem.